# Close all open drop downs and consolidate code if possible

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

**What I need to be able to do is to have the text drop downs close when another is selected so that I do not end up with a bunch of drop downs open on the page at the same time.**

I have two text dropdowns that will be used one after the other alternating on a page. In other words accordion1, accordion2, accordion1, accordion2 and so on the reason I have accordion1 and accordion2 is that with my limited experience it is the only way I could figure out change the button color so the list could alternate colors. It would be nice to consolidate the code, but I can live with the extra code if need be.

Here is the code for accordion1

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion1");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active1");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active1");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion2 {
  background-color: #8461E8;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the 
      .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

.active1,
.accordion1:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

.panel1 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion1:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion2:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active1:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<Section><button class="accordion1"><h3>Alternators and regulators</h3> 
    </button>
  <div id="accordion1-div" class="panel1">
    <p>First group of words go here></div>
</Section>

<Section><button class="accordion2"><h3>Batteries and Inverters</h3> 
    </button>
  <div id="accordion-div" class="panel1">
    <p>Second set of words go here.</p>
  </div>
</Section>

<Section><button class="accordion1"><h3>AC and DC Panels </h3> 
    </button>
  <div id="accordian1-div" class="panel1">
    <p>Third set of words reusing "accordion1 go here"</p>
  </div>
</Section>
```

Any help or resources to figure out the needed code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use :even and :odd css rules to handle the alternating colors. You can also have more than one class per element so there is no need for the duplicated accordion script. What if you just keep a reference to the currently opened element? Every time a new element is clicked, remove the active class from the currently opened element and then store the newly click element. If you post some html, we can help you refine your js.

Comment: JasonB ... Thank you for responding .. html added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1 — "How do I not end up with a bunch of drop downs open on the page at the same time":**

You close all dropdowns before opening another one. You can also create css rules to display or hide the dropdown. This way, it will be easier to find the currently active dropdown. See code below.

**Question 2 — "How can I make the list alternate colors"**

You can add more than one class to an element. Simply create color classes and add them to the right elements. See code below.

Notes:

- Use the CSS selectors instead of JavaScript to show/hide the panel
- [Element h3 is not allowed as child of element button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Do it the other way round.
- Use the same JavaScript code and CSS for all accordions.

**Edit (scrollIntoView)**

I added code to automatically scroll the window so that the active tab is visible. 
It works only on Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Use this polyfill [iamdustan/smoothscroll](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/) to use it in other browsers. [See compatibility here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview) and [all functions here](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/).

```js
// Query all accordions
var accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Get the currently active accordion
    var active = document.querySelector('.accordion.active');

    // If there is one, deactivate it
    if (active) {
      active.classList.remove('active');
    }

    // Activate the new accordion, if it's not the one you just deactivated
    if (active !== this) {
      this.classList.add('active');
      
      // Use scrollIntoView to adjust the window scroll position to show the content.
      this.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion .header button {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  color: #444;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Set the color according to the modifier class */

.accordion.gray button {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.accordion.purple button {
  background-color: #8461E8;
}

.accordion.active button,
.accordion button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.accordion .panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Show the panel if the accordion is active */

.accordion.active .panel {
  display: block;
}

.accordion button:after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion.active button:after {
  content: "\2796";
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- Each accordion is wrapped by a div with the class 'accordion' -->
  <!-- 'accordion' is the component, 'gray' is the color modifier -->
  <div class="accordion gray">
    <!-- h3 can contain a button -->
    <h3 class="header">
      <button>Alternators and regulators</button>
    </h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        First group of words go here.<br/> I'm afraid I just blue myself. No… but I'd like to be asked! Michael! It's called 'taking advantage.' It's what gets you ahead in life. Now, when you do this without getting punched in the chest, you'll have
        more fun.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <!-- Use the 'purple' modifier class here -->
  <div class="accordion purple">
    <h3 class="header">
      <button>Batteries and Inverters</button>
    </h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        Second set of words go here.<br/> Steve Holt! I don't criticize you! And if you're worried about criticism, sometimes a diet is the best defense. That's why you always leave a note! Well, what do you expect, mother? I don't criticize you! And
        if you're worried about criticism, sometimes a diet is the best defense.<br/>
        <br/> Across from where? As you may or may not know, Lindsay and I have hit a bit of a rough patch. Now, when you do this without getting punched in the chest, you'll have more fun. No… but I'd like to be asked!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="accordion gray">
    <h3 class="header">
      <button>AC and DC Panels 
    </button>
    </h3>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>
        Third set of words go here.<br/> That's why you always leave a note! Not tricks, Michael, illusions. As you may or may not know, Lindsay and I have hit a bit of a rough patch. It's called 'taking advantage.' It's what gets you ahead in life.<br/>
        <br/> Say goodbye to these, because it's the last time! First place chick is hot, but has an attitude, doesn't date magicians. I'm afraid I just blue myself. I'm afraid I just blue myself. I'm afraid I just blue myself.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Barthy ... thank you for the code, I have tried it and it works  well. The only issue I am running into is that if you have a long string of text say in the first panel and you scroll down and select the next panel you do not see the text in the newly selected panel as you are still scrolled down after the new section is made. Not to big a deal on a desk top, but bigger deal on a phone screen. Is there anything that could be added to the script to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you could adjust the scrolling position of the window to show the appropriate content. Although that is an entirely different issue, which can be solved by different approaches, I will edit my answer to show you one possible way. In general, this is something you should try out by yourself and then only ask about if you find yourself stuck and have specific question to ask.

Comment: Barthy … This works exactly as I was hoping, thank you again you are a life saver.
I actually did try several approaches throughout the day yesterday, but everything I came up with was very clunky and involved creating separate div names for each panel and then having to create a separate script for each panel as there will be around 10 panels it was going to get messy and code heavy in a hurry. Thank you again for your simple and elegant solution.